# Selenium package "com.thoughtworks" cannot be resolved in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, selenium

I want to make a Selenium project with Eclipse. I have added the reference to the `selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar` file but I cannot import the package `com.thoughtworks` so the following lines produce an error:

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;
```

Comment: Where did you add the reference?

Comment: might be these packages renamed/ removed in the latest selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium RC has become obsolete in the newer selenium versions.
Download Selenium server 2.43 jar file, include it in your project and your issue will be gone.